# How to customize elements of the Azure AD B2C page while still using Azure's template

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My business has the requirement of doing below changes while still using Azure blue template in Azure B2C's login page. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

[B2C login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa3T9.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you need styling customization you need to go with your own template. If you want to be as close to the default one provided then you need to download it, change and use as your custom one. To do that just open Developer Tools in the browser, open your user flow and find something similar to this (image below) in the Network tab of Developer Tools:

[image]

Just double click it and the new page with template used with your flow will open. Just save it as HTML and you are free to go. Don't forget about checking any extenal references (CSS, JS, etc). Depending on what will you be changing you might want to download them and host on your own as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy